# How can I escape nginx keywords with format()

Tags: python, templates, nginx, format

I'm working on an automated script for populating some configuration files for a server, and I'm having a problem with the nginx configuration file. It contains two types of recognized format() keywords (`$` and `{}`) and I want just to populate the ones with curly braces. The problem is that I can't escape the keywords like $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for (I should be able with `$$` but it doesn't work for some reason) and the script returns KeyErrors. Does anybody have and idea of how can I escape this?

**nginx.conf (instance_name in this case)**

```
location /{instance_name} {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /{instance_name};
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass unix:/var/run/openmooc/askbot/{instance_name}.sock;
}
```

**The replacement code:**

```
def _populate_file(self, original_file, values):

    """
    Basic abstraction layer for populating files on demand

    original_file has to be a path to the file in string format
    values is a dictionary containing the necessary key:value pairs.
    """
    f = open(original_file, 'r')
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    # Create a new populated file. We use ** so we can use keyword replacement
    populated_settings = file_content.format(**values)
    # Open the file in write mode so we can rewrite it
    f = open(original_file, 'w')
    f.write(populated_settings)
    f.close()

# Call to action
template = os.path.join(INSTANCE_DIR, 'nginx.conf')
values = {'instance_name': instance_name}
self._populate_file(template, values)
```

**SOLVED**: As @Blender said, format() is taking the entire location block as a keyword to replace. The simplest solution was to put double curly braces to escape them. The solution from @FoxMaSk is also right, but it wasn't what I was looking for

Comment: You're getting a KeyError because Python is trying to format the *entire* block inside of the curly braces.

Comment: D'oh! Quite right @Blender I didn't saw that coming... thanks!

Comment: @Blender can you put your comment as an answer so I can check it as the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `KeyError` because Python is trying to format the entire block (`{\n    proxy_set_header ... }`) inside of the curly braces.

You may find it easier to use the old string formatting syntax:

```
"""location /%(instance_name)s {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /%(instance_name)s;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass unix:/var/run/openmooc/askbot/%(instance_name)s.sock;
}""" % {'instance_name': 'foo_bar'}
```

Or just do a manual search-replace, as [@FoxMaSk suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18459266/464744).

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
populated_settings = file_content.format(**values)
```

a str.replace should do the trick

```
populated_settings = file_content.replace('{instance_name}',values['instance_name'])
```

Comment: I'll certainly take a look to that, but I have to cover more use cases and I don't know if I can use replace() in all of them. Good answer though :)